# Syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in for each loop

Tags: php, syntax-error

[image: code image]
.

Hi, this is my code, don't know why but I have a stupid syntax error,on the marked line. 
Please bring some light for a php nob.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' in /var/www/stats/upd_tr_stats.php  on line 38
```

Comment: paste your code in as text. It makes it much easier for us to debug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a `while` loop instead of a `for`.

Comment: @Tom - I think that's a slam dunk. Good show, sir!

Comment: +1 because that's probably what he wants

Comment: Thanks Tom and everybody else. I got a wrong example from google.

Answer (score 3):

in [php.net](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
statement
```

so, your for function doesn't have three expression.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a foreach statement, but a for statement. That's why it is expecting a ;

But you are still missing a part.